# Dynamic translation of combobox qml

Tags: qt, qml

I've added translation to my qt/qml app using this tutorial

https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2017/01/04/translating-qml-app/
https://github.com/retifrav/translating-qml

And most seems to work well except that the values of the combobox dont get update with dynamic translate.
Im using qt 5.11.2.

By a combobox i mean this:

```
ComboBox {
    textRole: "text"
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    model: ListModel {
        Component.onCompleted: {
            append({text: qsTr("None")})
            append({text: qsTr("Subpanel")})
            append({text: qsTr("All")})
        }
    }
}
ComboBox {
    textRole: "text"
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    model: ListModel {
            ListElement{text: qsTr("None")}
            ListElement{text: qsTr("Subpanel")}
            ListElement{text: qsTr("All")}
    }
}
```

None of them gets updated.
I've done some research and found this on bug reports
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68350
This seems to get fixed on 5.12, but for various reason we need to keep the same version, is there a way i can fix it for this version? (5.11.2)

EDIT: I dont find a way to translate comboBox. Is there another way of doing translations? even if it means to open a new instance of the app? Can someone point me to a link? Can't find a way to do this.

EDIT2: Is there a way to force the model of the combobox to be updated by javascript? when the changeLanguage() method is called?

note: As a complaint i'm finding the support / community to get answers for Qt problems terrible, really bad, but maybe its my problem.

Comment: Create hidden `Label`s and define the texts there. Then let the list elements bind to those labels. That could work

Comment: Or create a QAbstractListModel with your texts, this way you can even tie a certain value to a certain text

Comment: @Felix that doesnt work.

Comment: @Amfasis can you give an example on how i can do that? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't test all the cases at the moment (and I don't have an access to the Qt 5.11.2), but I think this should work:

```
    ComboBox {
        textRole: "text"
        Layout.fillWidth: true

        displayText: qsTr(currentText)

        model: ListModel {
            ListElement{text: "None"}
            ListElement{text: "Subpanel"}
            ListElement{text: "All"}
        }
        delegate: Button {
            width: ListView.view.width
            text: qsTr(model.text)
        }
    }
```

Or, another way is to re-create a model when language is changed:

```
    ComboBox {
        id: combobox
        textRole: "text"
        Layout.fillWidth: true

        model: ListModel {
            dynamicRoles: true
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {
            reload()
        }

        Connections {
            target: trans // this is a translator from a git project you are referring to
            onLanguageChanged: {
                combobox.reload()
            }
        }

        function reload() {
            var i = combobox.currentIndex
            combobox.model = [
                        {text: qsTr("None")},
                        {text: qsTr("Subpanel")},
                        {text: qsTr("All")}
                    ]
            combobox.currentIndex = i
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the first example you need to use `QT_TR_NOOP` in the `ListModel` so that `lupdate` knows there is a string to be translated

Comment: @Amfasis, could you please clarify why do I need to use it?

Comment: The tool that searches for text that should be translated (`lupdate`) does not look through if there is a variable in the `qsTr(...)` call, so it will not translate the three items in your `ListModel` (ok, there is a chance it will find the same text already translated and use that, but that's not good programming IMHO)

Comment: why if i use on the text: qsTr("&") it appears on the items as an underscore? "_"

Answer (score 2):

One option is to add a `QAbstracstListModel` which does the translation. I made myself a base class, which can be inherited. This also gives you a lot of flexibility for converting a selected item to a value (in this example I am using int, but you can make it anything), which is connected to a C++ backend (I used `backend.selectedPanel` for your example)

**<< Edit: See answer of Felix for nice addition of dynamic translation >>**

base header:

```
class baseEnum : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const = 0;
    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const = 0;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;

    Q_INVOKABLE int getIndex(int value);
    Q_INVOKABLE int getValue(int index);
}
```

base cpp:

```
QHash<int, QByteArray> baseEnum::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> result;
    result.insert(Qt::DisplayRole, "text");
    result.insert(Qt::UserRole + 1, "value");
    return result;
}

int baseEnum::getIndex(int value)
{
    for(int i=0;i<rowCount(QModelIndex());++i)
        if(data(createIndex(i, 0, nullptr), Qt::UserRole + 1).toInt() == value)
            return i;

    return -1;
}

int baseEnum::getValue(int index)
{
    return data(createIndex(index, 0, nullptr), Qt::UserRole + 1).toInt();
}
```

derived header:

```
class FancyEnum : public baseEnum
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
};
```

derived cpp:

```
int FancyEnum::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if(!parent.isValid())
        return 5;

    return 0;
}

QVariant FancyEnum::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    switch(index.row())
    {
    case 0: return role == Qt::DisplayRole ? QVariant(tr("None"))     : QVariant(0);
    case 1: return role == Qt::DisplayRole ? QVariant(tr("Subpanel")) : QVariant(1);
    case 2: return role == Qt::DisplayRole ? QVariant(tr("All"))      : QVariant(2);
    }

    return role == Qt::DisplayRole ? QVariant(QString("<%1>").arg(index.row())) : QVariant(0);
}
```

Register it somewhere:

```
qmlRegisterType<FancyEnum>("your.path.here", 1, 0, "FancyEnum");
```

usage in QML:

```
ComboBox {
    model: FancyEnum { id: myEnum }
    textRole: "text"
    currentIndex: myEnum.getIndex(backend.selectedPanel) : 0
    onActivated: backend.selectedPanel = myEnum.getValue(index) }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. i tried this solution i added the 2 classes, registeres the type on the main.cpp (qmlRegisterType<FancyEnum>("pt.gfe.connector", 1, 0, "FancyEnum");) and the called the model in combobox like you do but doesn't work. Is this tested to work? (in QT version 5.11)

Comment: You will propably have to capture the retranslate event and "reset" the model so the gui gets notified of the change

Comment: @Felix how do you suggest doing that?

Comment: @Nmaster88 This is already used in production code, albeit not with the dynamic translation. Is that what you describe as not working?

Comment: @Amfasis yes, my problem is related with dynamic translation.

Comment: @Amfasis I've registered the qmlRegisterType in main function, is it ok there?

Comment: @Nmaster88 yes that's fine. In the end you might want to move them to a separate function if your project grows, but it's a nice starting point

Answer (score 2):

*This is an addition to @Amfasis answer. It extends the very useful "baseEnum" model by adding the capability to detect and react to restranslation events*

---

For the GUI to actually detect that the text was changed after a restranslation, the model must "notify" the gui that data has changed. However, to do that, the model must know when data changed. Thankfully, Qt has the LanguageChange event to do so. The following code catches that event and uses it to notify the gui of the data change.

```
// in the header file:

class baseEnum : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    // ... all the stuff from before

    bool event(QEvent *event);
};

// and in the cpp file:

bool baseEnum::event(QEvent *ev)
{
    if(ev) {
        switch(ev->type()) {
        case QEvent::LanguageChange:
            // notifiy models that the display data has changed for all rows
            emit dataChanged(index(0),
                             index(rowCount(QModelIndex{}) - 1),
                             {Qt::DisplayRole});
            break;
        }
    }

    return QAbstractListModel::event(ev);
}
```

Comment: thanks for this addition :-D I will actually also start using it in my projects :thumbsup:

Comment: @Felix i've added those function to baseEnum class, but rowCount() is not defined there, it's on fancyEnum, how do i call that function? thanks

Comment: It is declared as pure virtual function and implemented in the FancyEnum model. You can still call it from the base class just like any other normal method

Comment: @Nmaster88 I also got an error, needed to put `rowCount(QModelIndx())` instead. Also `event(QEvent*)` is expected to have a bool return value in my version of Qt, not sure if it was changed

Comment: Ah yes, I simply screwed up the bool part. Also, In `QAbstractListModel`, rowCount is declared as `int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const` - which is why you can call it without a parameter normally - but as I can see now, in @Amfasis answer he did not specify the default argument again. I will update my answer accordingly